# Picking up high frequency in fast fourier transform and inverse fourier transforms

Tags: python, fft

Given a function f(t) and its second derivative, ddf(t)==g(t), I am interested in how their Fourier transforms relate. Mathematically speaking, noting F(w) and G(w) the transforms of f(t) and g(t) respectively, we should have

G(w) = -w^2F(w)

I wanted to investigate this numerically in Python and I am hitting the common roadblocks that I never completely understood in the Gibbs effect, and ringing effects when handling discrete fourier transforms. Below is the mwe python code snippet I was working with.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq, ifft
t=np.linspace(-5,5,100)
dt=t[1]-t[0]
w=fftfreq(len(t),dt)
a=3.0

#some sigmoid function
f=1/(1+np.exp(-a*t))
plt.plot(f)
Fw=fft(f) #its fourier transform

plt.plot(np.real(4*np.pi*np.pi*ifft(-Fw*w*w))) #The ifft/fft way of computing the     second derivative
plt.plot(np.gradient(np.gradient(f))/dt**2) #the finite difference way of computing     the second derivative

plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.legend(['f(t)',r'ifft(fft(-$\omega^2$F[$\omega$]))]','ddf(t)'], fontsize=15)
```

[This is the result of this code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJV0F.png)

Computing the second derivative as the inverse transform of -F[w]*w^2 should in principle yield the second derivative of f(t). But I am picking up extremely large weights at either end of my time scale, and there is a high frequency ringing on top of my signal.
I am aware this might originate from rounding issues in frequency space or improperly binned frequencies, but I do not know how to correct these issues and do not fully understand them. The results do not depend on how fine-grained the time axis is.

Any help appreciated

Comment: The fourier transform expects a periodic input signal. Your input signal is far from periodic as f(0) = 0 and f(N-1) = 1

Comment: An FFT is an implementation of the *discrete Fourier transform* [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) which is not quite the same as the integral Fourier transform (as noted elsewhere, it assumes periodicity over its range, as well as discrete samples in both the forward and inverse directions). The ringing is essentially due to the high-frequency power added by that induced jump from 1 to 0.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. To understand precisely, the ringing comes from the fact that implicitly, my first and last data points are considered a step-function in my supposedly periodic signal ?